# Switch to classic and modern

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it allowed to create a root site as classic experience and switch back to modern and vise versa

I can't find the switch link for experience in SharePoint online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a link for switching site layout to classic in 'Site Contents'. You can go from the gear like button on the top right corner of the sharepoint page, then click on site contents. On the redirected page at the bottom left most part of the page, you can see a link "Switch to classic" then you can also switch back to modern if you are in classic from there.

IF your goal is you wanted a page / create a page that is a classic, you can just go to site pages then click on webpart page. It will create a classic page and do some usual sharepoint classic stuffs on that page.

Hope the concept helps, Happy Learning!

Answer (score 2):

You can switch list and library experience using following way.

[image]

Check the full [Microsoft article here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9).

Answer (score 1):

Every site template supports both [classic and modern experiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f) in SharePoint Online.

A SharePoint Online site uses **modern** experience for lists/libraries by default.

In normal occasions, you will find a link under the left navigation that allows you to switch between these two experiences temporarily.

(This is not available in Communication sites since they do not have left navigations.)

[image]

And to switch to another experience permanently, you need to change it via `List/Library Settings > Advanced settings > List experience`.

[image]